# Is there a managed property which contains the url of user profile picture

Tags: user-profile-property, managed-property, picture

I want to add user profile pic in a custom display template. I cannot find any managed property which contains the url. thanks

Answer (score 1):

`PictureURL` - User Profile picture property

[PeopleManager.SetMyProfilePicture method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.peoplemanager.setmyprofilepicture.aspx) uploads and sets the user profile picture

[UserProfile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofile.aspx)[PropertyConstants.PictureUrl].Value gets user profile picture url

Comment: ok, I cannot find PictureURL when I search for it in Manged Properties.